# Registering BroadcastReceivers from singleton

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a singleton class to report connectivity status. The idea being, I can reuse this "service" anywhere in my app e.g:

```
getApplication().getConnectivityStatus().isConnected()
```

The singleton has a reference to the ApplicationContext.

I'd like to use a BroadcastReceiver behind the scenes to detect connectivity changes. I'm registering and unregistering it dynamically within the connectivity "service" to implement a higher level listener for connectivity e.g:

```
getApplication().getConnectivityStatus().onConnectivity(mConnectivityCallback)
```

I only want the BroadcastReceiver to be registered at my discretion. I see a hole here, though, when the app is killed. Since there are no lifecycle callbacks for Application, there's nothing I can hook onto to unregister the BroadcastReceiver if the app is killed.

So, 1: my app dies but the BroadcastReceiver (with its reference to the ApplicationContext) stays registered and its onReceive method gets called... Do bad things happen?

2: Is there any way to cleanly do what I'm trying to do here or is my pattern just misconceived?

Comment: I believe your concern is a valid one, as I had the same thought. Just adding as a comment here instead of an answer. If (like me) you are using local broadcasts, you do not need not worry about memory leaks in the above situation. Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349588/locally-managed-broadcast-receiver-leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply create `BroadcastReceiver` [registered](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

From that receiver you could update your singleton's connection status and you don't have to be worried about unregistering. If you don't want to other classes be able to change status, put receiver and singleton classes in the separate package and make setter method visibility to the package only.

**Update**

Your idea sound really interesting, having hermetic "service" that handles network changes and inform registered listeners. But, at the end your listeners are Activites which means that there will always be one listener at a time. Moreover, you cannot keep strong references to Activity in long lived objects and you have to use Activite's lifecycle callbacks.

I came to the conclusion that it would be better for you to go with very simple pattern(which I used to implement) of manager class.

Manager class could look like this:

```
public class NetworkManager {

    private boolean connected;
    private NetworkCallback callback;

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateStatus(context);
        }
    };

    private void updateStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = conn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        //TODO do the rest here, e.g. set connected flag
        connected = networkInfo.isConnected();
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onConnectionChanged(connected);
        }
    }

    public void registerContext(Context context, NetworkCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        updateStatus(context);
    }

    public void unregisterContext(Context context) {
        callback = null;
        context.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    public interface NetworkCallback {

        void onConnectionChanged(boolean connected);
    }
}
```

It doesn't have to be a singleton if it's used by Activity only.

And Activity that use it:

```
public class NetworkActivity extends Activity implements NetworkManager.NetworkCallback {

    private NetworkManager networkManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        networkManager = new NetworkManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        networkManager.registerContext(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        networkManager.unregisterContext(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionChanged(boolean connected) {
        //TODO do something here
    }
}
```

**Hint**

Do not force yourself to create code using sophisticated Patterns where it is not needed. Use Patterns only if your application actually benefit from their advantages.

Comment: Ah, nice and simple! Thanks. :) One addition: since I want to register listeners on this thing I think I'll need to use a combination of a singleton and then "client" instances which are attached to the Activity lifecycles. That way, listeners can be registered with the "clients" and can be created/die with Activities as needed. Otherwise I'll wind up with stale listeners in that singleton.

Comment: You can use WeakReference class for storing list of registered listeners("clients") in your singleton. When Activity dies, listener will also die and you don't need to care about unregistering. Otherwise, you have to handle unregistering Activity outside of the "service".

Comment: Hmm, didn't think of that... But actually then you'd have to wait for garbage collection for the listener to disappear. Since the validity of the listener depends on the lifecycle status of the listening component, I don't think there's any option but to do things manually via lifecycle callbacks.

Comment: Re your update: Technically it could be used by anything with a context, meaning at very least by both an Activity and Service simultaneously. I think this is maybe the one advantage of using the singleton/client pattern I mentioned. Otherwise it looks the same from an API standpoint (with the drawback of being more complicated to implement). And your hint is well taken, thank you :)

Comment: Well ok, this can also be used by both simultaneously... so yeah, I'll go with your pattern, it's much simpler.

Answer (score -1):

Here am posting sample code who test internet connection through service and let user know is internet present or not through service may it will help you

BroadcastReceiverClass.java

```
    package com.sample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BroadcastReceiverClass extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {

    Context _con;

    public BroadcastReceiverClass(Context _con) {
        this._con = _con;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
        intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

        NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

        if (currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(_con, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(_con, "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

BroadCastSampleActivity .java

```
package com.sample;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class BroadCastSampleActivity extends Activity {
    BroadcastReceiverClass mConnReceiver;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiverClass(this);
        this.registerReceiver(mConnReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        // this.unregisterReceiver(mConnReceiver);
    }

    // private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    // public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,
    // false);
    // intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
    // intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);
    //
    // NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
    // .getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    // intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);
    //
    // if (currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected",
    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // } else {
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected",
    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // }
    // }
    // };
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////
manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.sample"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".BroadCastSampleActivity"
                  android:label="BroadCast">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question. I was asking whether BroadcastReceiver could be used in a different pattern.